# Is it possible to add Crystal Reports into .NET Core app targetting 4.6

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, crystal-reports, asp.net-core

I am currently trying to develop a small web application for a business. I started development using .NET Core 1.1 version. And when I tried to study how to add Crystal Reports into the project, it is said that they are not supporting it yet.

Is it possible to add Crystal Reports if I change my target framework to 4.6 in the .NET Core app? Or do I have to start a new web application targeting .NET Framework project 4.6.2 from scratch again?

Comment: I think it's very quick to change the target framework - can you please try that?

Answer (score 1):

This should absolutely work.  When targeting the full framework like 4.6 with Asp.Net Core you have access to *any* dlls that are based on 4.6 that you create project references to.

If the makers of Crystal Reports said they are not supporting it yet, perhaps they mean they are not supporting it via direct reference from a project json file but even that seems suspect.  But now with VS 2017 the project json is no longer used and .Net Core projects use a regular cs proj file fairly similar to what non .Net Core projects have always uses.  So again, use VS2017 you should absolutely be able to reference Crystal Reports Dlls directly and you should be able to reference a full framework class library that references a Crystal Reports DLL.

Another possibility is that maybe their designer support tooling needs updated in some way for .Net Core Projects.  But even if that's the case, running an existing report should work.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to find the DLLs needed to add Crystal Reports in the app? It doesn't show up in References like in a .NET 4.6 web app.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use crystal reports anymore and my backups don't go far enough back.  But when I did use it I could created link to Crystal Reports from a Windows Library dll and locate  my reports in that dll.  Then I could reference that dll from both a Win Forms project and a Web forms project.  And from my latest work know that Windows Library dlls are referencable from a Web Project targeting the full framework.  So it kinda has to work.